# Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['todos\\/detail\\/(?P<id>[0-9]+)\\/$']

Tags: django, django-urls

I m trying to build a  todo app in django. Having a problem while link to detail page unable to link up to the page.
here is my code.

```
**todos/index.html:**
 {% if todo %}

    <ul>

    {% for todos in todo %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'todos:detail' todo.id %}">{{ todos.text }}</a></li>

    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No Todo list are available.</p>
{% endif %}


view.py:

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Todo
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    todo =Todo.objects.all()
    context={'todo':todo}
    return render(request, 'todos/index.html',context)

def detail(request,id):
    todo =Todo.objects.get(id=id)
    context={'todo':todo}
    return render(request, 'todos/detail.html',context)


  todos/url.py:
app_name ="todos"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('detail/<int:id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

**I have to actually click on the  to activate the link:

[{{ todos.text }}](/todos/detail/%7B%20todo.id%20%7D)

.

it works but it did not take me to the detail page**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking `id` for wrong variable. So update the code like following(I am using [empty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) tag for handling empty `todos`):

```
<ul>
    {% for todos in todo %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'todos:detail' todos.id %}">{{ todos.text }}</a></li>  // Changed here from todo.id to todos.id
    {% empty %}
    <li> No ToDos </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: i do not know the process of accepting the answer@ruddra

Comment: You can check this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/251344